# Rest API contribution get doesn't return display_name

Tags: contacts, api, contributions

in my Civicrm 5.31 on Wordpress 5.5 I'm trying to retrieve contribution data via Rest API, using the apiExplorer I get the code:

```
wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/extern/rest.php?entity=Contribution&action=get&api_key=userkey&key=sitekey&json={"sequential":1,"return":"contact_id,contribution_source,total_amount,fee_amount,trxn_id,invoice_number","receive_date":{">":"01/01/2021"}}
```

but if I try to add the display_name it doesn't work. I try: contact_id.display_name and display_name

Answer (score 1):

You're in a bit of a tough spot, I'm afraid.

- The display name is attached to the contact, not the contribution.
- You would typically use an API join to handle this.  However, joining to the Contact entity isn't supported in APIv3.  It *is* supported in APIv4 (and in fact is one of the main reasons behind API4).
- However, [API4 doesn't have a REST interface](https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1310) at present.

So you have two options:

- Make 2 REST calls;
- Try to use [APIv3 chaining](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/api/v3/chaining/).  This will let you make a single REST call, but does NOT reduce the number of API calls made internally.  I've always found it to be more trouble than it's worth though, and I shudder to think about what that would look like over REST.

Comment: Now it is more clear and I finally understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: It is strange that is I choose some fields it give me these, but if I choose a not existing field it give me more fields with the display_name (it is possible to check it also in the api explorer). I trying the chaing mode, but I have to study because I don't know how it works (the documentation is not showing how to pass a variable to the chain)